# How to store text input in a vector to be used later with R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to define two variables ("tickers" and "SharesVec") as empty vectors and add text inputs and numerical inputs (respectively) to these vectors when the button "action" is triggered. I will be using these vectors later to run a function. I'm not sure I understand how to use variables properly in R shiny (beginner). Here is what I tried so far:

UI

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    
    titlePanel("Portfolio Analysis Tool"),
    br(),
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput(
                inputId =  "DateFrom", 
                label = "Starting Year (YYYY-01-01)", 
                choices = format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"):1975    
            ),
            selectInput(
                inputId =  "DateTo", 
                label = "Ending Year (YYYY-12-31)", 
                choices = format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"):1975    
            ),
            h2("Initial Portfolio"),
            p("Include every ticker owned at some point during the period (Number of shares = 0 if none are held at the starting date)", style = "font-size: 12px"),
            textInput("Stock","Ticker"),
            numericInput("Shares","Number of Shares",0, min = 0, step = 0.5),
            column(12,
                  splitLayout(cellWidths = c("58%", "58%"),
                        actionButton("action", "Add",icon("dollar-sign"),  
                            style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"),
                        actionButton("action1", "Reset",icon("trash"),  
                            style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"))),
            br(),
            br(),
            h2("Rebalancing"),
            dateInput("DateReb", "Date of Purchase/Sale"),
            textInput("Stock1", "Ticker"),
            numericInput("Shares1","Number of Shares (+/-)", 0, step = 0.5),
            column(12,
                   splitLayout(cellWidths = c("58%", "58%"),
                               actionButton("action2", "Add",icon("dollar-sign"),  
                                            style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"),
                               actionButton("action3", "Reset",icon("trash"),  
                                            style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"))),
            br(),
            br(),
        ),
        
        mainPanel(
            column(10,
                   splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"),
                               htmlOutput("InitialHoldings", style = "font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline"),
                               htmlOutput("Rebalancing", style = "font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline"))),
            br(),
            br(),
            column(12,
                tableOutput("table"), 
                style = "height:340px; overflow-y: scroll; border: 1px solid #e3e3e3; border-radius: 8px; background-color: #f7f7f7;text-align: left"),
            textOutput("TEST")
       )
    )
))
```

Server

```
library(quantmod)                            
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

tickers <- c()
SharesVec <- c()

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    
  output$InitialHoldings <- renderText({paste("Initial Holdings")})
  output$Rebalancing <- renderText({paste("Rebalancing")})

  #Store Initial Stocks/Nb of Shares from User Inputs
  values <- reactiveValues()
  values$df <- data.frame("Stock" = numeric(0), "Shares" = numeric(0))
  newEntry <- observe({
    if(input$action > 0) {
      isolate(values$df[nrow(values$df) + 1,] <- c(input$Stock, input$Shares))
      tickers <- c(tickers,input$Stock)
      SharesVec <- c(SharesVec,input$Shares)
    }
  })
  output$table <- renderTable({values$df})
  output$TEST <- renderText({paste(tickers)})

})
```

Note: I have included output$TEST in the code to see if the vector "tickers" updates itself properly. Also, I want to point out that since I added the lines

```
tickers <- c(tickers,input$Stock)
SharesVec <- c(SharesVec,input$Shares)
```

in the server, the action button doesn't work properly (it's no longer needed to add data to my table). I have also tried using global variables ->> but it didn't seem to work.. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the vectors in `reactiveValues`. You can change the server function to :

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  output$InitialHoldings <- renderText({paste("Initial Holdings")})
  output$Rebalancing <- renderText({paste("Rebalancing")})
  
  #Store Initial Stocks/Nb of Shares from User Inputs
  values <- reactiveValues(tickers = NULL, SharesVec = NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$action, {
    values$tickers <- c(values$tickers,input$Stock)
    values$SharesVec <- c(values$SharesVec,input$Shares)
  })
    
  output$TEST <- renderText({
       paste(values$tickers, values$SharesVec, sep = ':', collapse = '\n')
  })
  
}
```

Using `output$TEST` to show you the values that are stored.